# Is there any javascript word-boundary alternative for non-words?

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

Word boundary aka *\b* in javascript regex works only with words, not with non-words. So is there any alternative for non-word characters ?

e.g.

```
const a = " only ' ", b = " anything' ";
console.log(onlyquote(a)) //=> true
console.log(onlyquote(b)) //=> false
```

In constant *a*, the quote was free from any word attached to it, resulting the output as *true*, while in constant *b*, the quote was attached to letter *g*, hence output was false.

Comment: use \B, \B is non-words

Comment: In regex, `\b` is shorthand for `(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)`, and `\w` is shorthand for `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`. For that matter, there is a `\B` which is the negation of `\b`, but from what I can see that's not what you're looking for - you probably are looking for something like `(?<!\W)(?=\W)|(?<=\W)(?!\W)` which is the equivalent of `\b` but with non-alphanumeric characters. unfortunately your intention with this 'onlyquote' function isn't very clear so I we can't give you a proper answer

Comment: @Badashi The hint you gave me, is enough for me to continue learning. Thanks a lot !